# Get the result from a Task

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following `Task` which I want to `await`

```
public Task ShowWindow<TWindow>(TWindow window) where TWindow : Window
{
    var task = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    window.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    window.ShowDialog();
    task.SetResult(window.DialogResult ?? false);
    window.Focus();
    return task.Task;
}
```

This works perfectly when I call it:

```
private async void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await ShowWindow(new SettingsWindow());

    // more code
}
```

**How can I get access to the result of the `Task`?**
I imagined something like the following, but there is clearly something I've missed:

```
private async void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool result = await ShowWindow(new SettingsWindow());

    if(result == true)
        doSomething();
}
```

This gives me an error: `Await task returns no value`
But I am under the impression that I *am* returning something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `public Task ShowWindow` to `public Task<bool> ShowWindow`; a `Task` is the `async` equivalent of `void`; a `Task<T>` is the `async` equivalent of a method that returns `T`.

However, it doesn't look like there is any genuinely `async` code here; it looks like `ShowWindow` will run to completion on the calling thread, which might make `Task` (with or without a `<T>`) redundant.

Comment: it actually does something: it enables the flicker when the parent window is clicked: [Flicker with async/await](https://imgur.com/x4ktHgG) vs. [No flicker with simply ShowDialog()](https://imgur.com/WFGMshS)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :)